# Продвинутый textarea

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

На сайтах есть textarea с кнопками наверху, на stackoverflow он тоже есть[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как они называются и готовые решения.

Comment: ты ленивый(больше не могу ничего сказать, модераторы ругаться будут)

Comment: гугли - WYSIWYG

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg я гулил, я не знаю как это описать поэтому ничего не нашел.

Comment: @ТерновойЕгор - так я и написал, как чаще всего они называются. На github целая куча решений. [Вот первое в списке](https://summernote.org/)

Comment: Ещё есть такой - [ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/)